# Python regex to remove capture email between dashes or ignore emails ending with .jpg etc

Tags: python, regex, email

I am trying to figure out how to improve the regex to only get `emails` not ending with `".jpg"` and to remove `--` from both left and right part of the emails if any is found. Example parameter as `source` which is a string.

```
<html>
   <body>
   <p>aaa@example.jpg</p>
   <p>--bbb@example.com--</p>
   <p>ccc@example.com--</p>
   <p>--ddd@example.com</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The result should contain: **bbb@example.com, ccc@example.com, ddd@example.com**
So basically, I want to see anyway to improve this function so the regex would could produce emails without -- and if possible improve the `if not email[0].endswith('.png')` in case i want to add more, this could look urgly.

```
def extract_emails(source):

    regex = re.compile(r'([\w\-\.]{1,100}@(\w[\w\-]+\.)+[\w\-]+)')
    emails = list(set(regex.findall(source.decode("utf8"))))
    all_emails = []
    for email in emails:
        if not email[0].endswith('.png') and not email[0].endswith('.jpg') \
                and not email[0].endswith('.gif') and not email[0].endswith('.rar')\
                and not email[0].endswith('.zip') and not email[0].endswith('.swf'):
            all_emails.append(email[0].lower())

    return list(set(all_emails))
```

Comment: @Epodax mistakenly selected all suggested tags.

Comment: Don't use regex, use html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x="""<html>
   <body>
   <p>aaa@example.jpg</p>
   <p>--bbb@example.com--</p>
   <p>ccc@example.com--</p>
   <p>--ddd@example.com</p>

</body>
</html>"""
print re.findall(r"-*([\w\-\.]{1,100}@(?:\w[\w\-]+\.)+(?!jpg)[\w]+)-*",x)
```

Output:`['bbb@example.com', 'ccc@example.com', 'ddd@example.com']`

Comment: would fail for this <p>222@example.jpg.com</p> clearly no perfect regex for email. but the regex by @Uchicha solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think top level domains are few so you can use `alternation`

```
s="""<html>
   <body>
   <p>aaa@example.jpg</p>
   <p>--bbb@example.com--</p>
   <p>ccc@example.com--</p>
   <p>--ddd@example.com</p>

</body>
</html>"""
print re.findall(r"-*([\w\.]{1,100}@\w[\w\-]+\.+com|biz|us|bd)-*",s)

['bbb@example.com', 'ccc@example.com', 'ddd@example.com']
```

see <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qH0bP4/3)</kbd>

or try `\w+@\w+\.(?!jpg|png)\w+\.*\w*`

```
s="""<html>
   <body>
   <p>aaa@example.jpg</p>
   <p>--bbb@example.com--</p>
   <p>ccc@example.com--</p>
   <p>--ddd@example.com</p>

</body>
</html>"""
print re.findall(r"\w+@\w+\.(?!jpg|png)\w+\.*\w*",s)
```

It is very hard to set constant regex for email verification-
Details for email validation go at [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) it has 69 answers.

Comment: without trying it i think it would not pass this: --ddd@example.com

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using html parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#)

```
In [37]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [38]: soup = BeautifulSoup('''<html>
   ....:    <body>
   ....:    <p>aaa@example.jpg</p>
   ....:    <p>--bbb@example.com--</p>
   ....:    <p>ccc@example.com--</p>
   ....:    <p>--ddd@example.com</p>
   ....:
   ....: </body>
   ....: </html>''', 'lxml')

In [39]: [email.strip('-') for email in soup.stripped_strings if not email.endswith('.jpg')]
Out[39]: ['bbb@example.com', 'ccc@example.com', 'ddd@example.com']
```